# Use of "that" in "A Rose for Emily" by William Faulkner

Tags: grammar

I am seeking a grammatical explanation for the usage of the two instances of 'that', which are emphasized in bold, in the following excerpts from "A Rose for Emily" by William Faulkner.

> What was left of him, rotted beneath what was left of the night-shirt, had become inextricable from the bed in which he lay; and upon him and upon the pillow beside him lay **that** even coating of the patient and biding dust.
>
> Then we noticed that in the second pillow was the indentation of a head. One of us lifted something from it, and leaning forward, **that** faint and invisible dust dry and acrid in the nostrils, we saw a long strand of iron-gray hair.

Comment: They're both demonstrative determiners: ***that** coating of dust*, the one that has already been alluded to a couple of sentences earlier, as opposed to just any coating of dust.

Comment: What did you try?  Where did you get stuck as you were trying to work this out?